# Is there a way to extract images from .ext file?

Tags: image, exe

Is there a way to get source images from .exe file? These images are use Md through the application.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Windows app you can try using "Resource Hacker".

http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

It can extract PNGs/JPGs, etc. from an executable file.

Comment: "What was new in 3.6.0 version:

Can decompile/compile 64-bit executable
Added PNG image support
Added PNG icons support"

Comment: Here's a link to patch notes and changelog. https://www.askvg.com/download-new-updated-resource-hacker-3-5-beta-with-64-bit-and-png-file-support/